# Can't catch the error after using throw error with react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, try-catch

I am trying to catch and throw an error between methods to render the error message.
My code

Login Action:

```
_auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then((userCredits) => {
           //some handle login code here
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("e: " + error);
            throw error;
        });
```

mapDispatchToProps:

```
startLogin: (user) => {
    try {
        dispatch(startLogin(user))
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("err in dipatching: " + e);
    }
},
```

And the final method call

```
 <LoginForm
            onSubmit={
                (user) => {
                    try {
                        props.startLogin(user);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        console.log("error: " + e);
                    }
                }}
        />
```

Problem is...after throwing the code in the first call, its never caught again, and I get the message

> Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.

Is there a special way to catch errors from dispatch calls? I am using try and catch everywhere and its still not caught...